# Linked in xml response to php variables

Tags: php, xml

i am getting this result from my linked in connect script,

```
<person>
  <email-address>xzenia1@gmail.com</email-address>
  <picture-url>http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_UiHHf6SiF4yuBerHUkfUfkshFpomUIrHMbpBf5Iy4sOYk7FecL4XTLxtdAEl42AXsho9hGzDtRBl</picture-url>
</person>
```

this is the php call

```
$xml_response = $linkedin->getProfile("~:(email-address,picture-url)");
```

how to make them assign to separate PHP variable.

Comment: Using an XML parser: http://php.net/simplexml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236047/how-do-i-create-variables-from-xml-data-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You can load your xml as string with [**`simplexml_load_string`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) and then loop in it to get all data

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_response);
foreach($xml as $key => $val)
{
    echo "$key=>$val<br>" . "\n";
}
```

This will output

```
email-address=>xzenia1@gmail.com
picture-url=>http://m3.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_UiHHf6SiF4yuBerHUkfUfkshFpomUIrHMbpBf5Iy4sOYk7FecL4XTLxtdAEl42AXsho9hGzDtRBl
```

[**Live sample**](http://ideone.com/c4TTYl)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
    $xml = (array)simplexml_load_string($xml_response);

    echo  $email=$xml['email-address'];
    echo $picture=$xml['picture-url'];
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with print and then assignign variables' value?

Comment: @Fabio,I just make an object to an array

Comment: Did you try this code?

Comment: @Fabio,yes,I got result.What is wrong with this??

Comment: Shin, this code doesn't make sense and is not working, see http://codepad.viper-7.com/7VfgNv

Comment: @michi,wHERE IS (array) IN YOUR CODE?$xml = (array)simplexml_load_string($xml_response); what you write for this statement???You missed (array),That is not my problem

Comment: @shin: Sorry for that. You're right, I stand corrected and learned sth new from you!

Comment: @michi,Okay..... I dont know this is a proper way,But i got result,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($linkedin->getProfile("~:(email-address,picture-url)"));

echo $xml->{'email-address'}[0] . "<br />";
echo $xml->{'picture-url'}[0];
```

`simplexml`doesn't like `-` in node names, therefore use `$xml->{'email-address'}` instead of `$xml->email-address`.

use index `[0]` on both nodes, just in case, if one day your `simplexml` object would contain more than one `<person>` node...

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/dQQ6sa