# how to get xml tag by name

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML:

```
<InternalData>
    <DataSet>
        <Table>
            <Expire_x0>2050-12-12T00:00:00+02:00</Expire_x0>
        </Table>
    </DataSet>
</InternalData>
```

How do I get the value of the `<Expire_x0>` tag?
I tried this:

```
$result = $s->__call("XmlString",array($params));
$obj_pros = get_object_vars($result);
$xml =  $obj_pros['XmlStringResult'];
$xml =  simplexml_load_string($xml);
$x = $xml->getElementsByTagName("Expire_x0");
echo $x;
```

without success. What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate question can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236047/how-do-i-create-variables-from-xml-data-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$expiresx0 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Expire_x0');
foreach ($expiresx0 as $expirex0) {
    echo $expirex0->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Or:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(xml); 
echo $xml->DataSet->Table->Expire_x0;
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Looks like you mixed both.

Comment: Not true. `InternalData` is root, please `var_dump($xml);`

Comment: You're right with InternalData (changed it), but `echo` was in the question so i leave echo here (var_dump won't cast simpleXmlObjects to a string...)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to get the value of the `<Expire_x0>` tag, for which you can use this code.

```
$xml = simple_xml_load_string($xml); //Load XML String
$xml = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true); //Convert to Standard PHP Array
$expire = $xml['InternalData']['DataSet']['Table']['Expire_x0']; //Find Tag Value
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$k = '<InternalData>
    <DataSet>
        <Table>
            <Expire_x0>2050-12-12T00:00:00+02:00</Expire_x0>
        </Table>
    </DataSet>
</InternalData>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($k);
    echo $xml->DataSet->Table->Expire_x0; 
}
```

Output

```
2050-12-12T00:00:00+02:00
```

Answer (score 0):

So many ways...

Which one is preferred?
is it better to use :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$expiresx0 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('Expire_x0');
```

or :

```
$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$xml2 = json_decode(json_encode($xml2), true); 

$expire = $xml2['DataSet']['Table']['Expire_x0'];
```

or maybe:

```
$xml1 =  simplexml_load_string($xml);
$x = $xml1->DataSet[0]->Table[0]->Expire_x0;
echo $x;
```

?

Answer (score -1):

You should use like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $xml->DataSet->Table->Expire_x0;
```

Do not use root tag `InternalData`

Comment: Yes and you can get root name with `$xml->getName();`

Comment: Why downvoted by who? You can try.. And if you downvoted, leave comment why unuseful!